# Implement Iterable in an immutable LinkedList in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, immutability, immutable-collections

I'm trying to understand the functional programming paradigm so I'm playing around with an immutable linked list. I've created a Bag with some utility functions and now I want to iterate through the collection. I want to implement an Iterable:

```
sealed class Bag<out A> : Iterable<A> {
    companion object {
        fun <A> of(vararg aa: A): Bag<A> {
            val tail = aa.sliceArray(1 until aa.size)
            return if (aa.isEmpty()) Nil else Cons(aa[0], of(*tail))
        }

        /**
         * Returns the tail of the bag
         */
        fun <A> tail(bag: Bag<A>): Bag<A> =
            when (bag) {
                is Cons -> bag.tail
                is Nil -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Nil cannot have a tail")
            }

        /**
         * Add an item to the beginning
         */
        fun <A> add(bag: Bag<A>, elem: A): Bag<A> =
            Cons(elem, bag)

        fun <A> isEmpty(bag: Bag<A>): Boolean =
            when (bag) {
                is Nil -> true
                is Cons -> false
            }
    }

    class BagIterator<A> : Iterator<A> {

        override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun next(): A {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    }
}

object Nil : Bag<Nothing>() {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<Nothing> =
        BagIterator()


}

data class Cons<out A>(val head: A, val tail: Bag<A>) : Bag<A>() {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<A> =
        BagIterator()
}
```

Now I'm stuck with hasNext() and next() implementations. I'm not even sure if this approach works. Can I implement Iterable this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that an `Iterator` is a mutable thing. `next` *must* mutate the iterator's current state. Its signature does not allow you to "return a new `Iterator` with a different state". So if you wanted to do that, sad news for you :( This is because the way that iteration is supposed to happen is (this is roughly what a `for` loop translates to):

```
val iterator = something.iterator()
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    val elem = iterator.next()
    ...
}
```

Now knowing that, we can store a `var current: Bag<A>`:

```
// in Bag<A>
class BagIterator<A>(var current: Bag<A>) : Iterator<A> {
    override fun hasNext(): Boolean = current !is Nil

    override fun next(): A {
        val curr = current
        return when (curr) {
            is Nil -> throw NoSuchElementException()
            is Cons -> curr.also {
                current = it.tail
            }.head
        }
    }
}

override fun iterator(): Iterator<A> = BagIterator(this)
```

And the `Nil` and `Cons` types can have empty bodies.

If you don't like this, blame the standard library designers :) You can always write your own `Iterator<A>` interface, but of course you can't use the `for` loop with your `Bag` if you do that. You *can* write your own `forEach` extension function though.

Comment: I got it, thanks. The "problem" is with the iterator itself